# C# - analogue of with keyword from Kotlin?

Tags: c#, kotlin

I want to something like with keyword in Kotlin to 
reduce the amount of repeated code like that:

```
fun printAlphabet() = with(StringBuilder()){
    for (letter in 'A'..'Z'){
        append(letter)
    }
    toString()
}
```

Any facilities?

Comment: What do you mean? You can already init an object's property using `with()` keyword

Comment: it's Kotlin language, I want to do the same in the C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `With` methods like this:

```
// you need a separate overload to handle the case of not returning anything
public static void With<T>(T t, Action<T> block) {
    block(t);
}

public static R With<T, R>(T t, Func<T, R> block) => block(t);
```

And then you can `using static` the class in which you declared the methods, and use it like this (translated code from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with)):

```
var list = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
With(list, x => {
    Console.WriteLine($"'with' is called with argument {x}");
    Console.WriteLine($"It contains {x.Count} elements");
    });
var firstAndLast = With(list, x => 
    $"The first element is {x.First()}. " +
    $"The last element is {x.Last()}.");
```

In your example, it would be used like this:

```
static string PrintAlphabet() => With(new StringBuilder(), x => {
        for (var c = 'A' ; c <= 'Z' ; c = (char)(c + 1)) {
            x.Append(c);
        }
        return x.ToString();
    });
```

Comment: Not sure that really gives much of an advantage over just doing `x = new StringBuilder(); ... x.Append(c); ... return x.ToString();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well, C# and Kotlin are different languages, so you gotta expect that some things don't map perfectly. However, one big difference between this `With` method and the approach you mentioned is that this `With` method is an _expression_, instead of a collection of statements. This enables it to be used as expression-bodied members, like I did with the `PrintAlphabet` method. `With` also reduces the number of local variables.

Comment: How to use With? "I get The name 'With' does not exist in the current context"

using static WithKeyword.With_;

namespace WithKeyword
{
    public static class With_
    {
        public static void With<T>(this T t, Action<T> block)
        {
            block(t);
        }
        public static R With<T, R>(this T t, Func<T, R> block) => block(t);
    }

Comment: @ДимаСоколов You need to add the line `using static WithKeyword.With_;` at the top of the file. Then you will be able to use `With` as if it were a global function.

Comment: probably not all method's signature work with using static

Comment: @ДимаСоколов Oops! I just noticed that I somehow accidentally wrote it as an extension method, which doesn't work with using static. Edited now.